# How to prompt engineer LLM using LangChain to give "unable to answer question" when asked a question

Tags: prompt, langchain, large-language-model

I am currently using LangChain and OpenAI to build a Natural Language to SQL model. The issue I am having is that I want the model to return "I don't know" or "Please provide more context" when answering a question as vague as "Number of rows". This is the current code I have below:

```html
_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = “”"Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct {dialect} query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer.
Use the following format:
Question: "Question here"
SQLQuery: "SQL Query to run"
SQLResult: "Result of the SQLQuery"
Answer: "Final answer here"

Only use the following tables: SDS_DataModel.Person and SDS_DataModel.Campus

SDS_DataModel.Person contains the following information: first name, last name, GreendaleID, email and net worth.
SDS_DataModel.Campus contains the following information: GPA, Graduation, GreendaleID, their on campus job and if they live on campus.
SDS_DataModel.Campus and SDS_DataModel.Person are joined by GreendaleID.

{table_info}

Never use LIMIT statement, use TOP statement instead.
Format all numeric response ###,###,###,###.
Ask as many clarifying questions as need be before answering.
Only return relevant columns to the question    
Question: {input}"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
input_variables=["input", "table_info", "dialect"], template=_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE
)

connection_string = "url"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(connection_string)
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, verbose=True, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct")
database_chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm,db, prompt=PROMPT)
sql_query = database_chain.invoke({"question": x})
```

I am unsure how to prompt engineer it or get threshold values so that the model doesn't answer the question if it doesnt have enough information or if it isnt confident enough.